# How to delete all red lines (causing error) once together? I am using Eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using ***Java*** and ***Eclipse Mars*** to write an application. Sometimes it happens that I do something somewhere in the code and then many other lines become red (Error) and I need to go through all the application and delete them one by one. I was wondering if it's possible to delete all red line once all together?

Comment: What do you do that casues red lines to appear everywhere? You delete whole classes or what?

Comment: Removing all the red lines won't help you. Why don't you trying to understand what went wrong and fix the application?

Comment: @JeffersonLima Thumbs up... I totally agree.

Comment: Ignore all but the first error line. Fixing that line will likely fix all of the others. Also note that it is possible that none of the red lines are actually incorrect; what is incorrect is whatever you did to cause them to be tagged as errors.

Comment: I am removing a variable from a class which has been used many times in that class, so that's why I have to go through all line that it has been called and delete them

Comment: Great idea for a compiler wrapper script: comment out all error lines, recursively until there are no errors! The downside is that a lot of the time the program ends up doing nothing, but you'd never have compiler errors again…